# How to make the div fixed on scroll in Skrollr code?

Tags: javascript, css, svg, skrollr

I want the SVG DIV to remain fixed on scroll. CSS didn't help. It ruins the code. Please answer.

If I use
`display:fixed;` in CSS, then the whole scrolling javascript doesn't work.

Here's the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/tashfene/58zNp/1/

Please help!

Comment: can you please tell me How did you do this? that is really cool

Comment: @Kermani : Its drawn on svg, you have to specify the coordinates

Answer (score 1):

Use `position:fixed` not `display:fixed`

I added it to your code inline: http://jsfiddle.net/58zNp/2/

Comment: Sorry I was TALKING about the SVG. Sorry again, for the ambiguity.

Comment: Okay, please edit your question then instead of asking the same question again

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24169805/how-to-make-the-svg-fixed-on-scroll-in-skrollr-code

Answer (score 0):

This is easy to do

you should add an css code to your H1

```
h1{
  position:fixed;
 }
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/kermani/58zNp/3/)

Comment: Thaanks. But I was talking about the SVG too. :p

Answer (score 0):

Use `position:fixed` instead of `display:fixed`

Comment: Sorry I was TALKING about the SVG. Sorry again, for the ambiguity