# How to make the SVG fixed on scroll in Skrollr code?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, svg

I want the SVG to remain fixed on scroll (Or maybe move with the speed of scroll to look fixed). CSS didn't help. It ruins the code. Please answer.

If I use `display:fixed;` in CSS, then the whole scrolling javascript doesn't work.

Here's the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/tashfene/58zNp/1/

Please help!

Comment: display:fixed doesn't exist :)

Comment: I tried making a div for it? Didn't work lol.

Comment: I visited your website, it seems your programming skill is well. can you tell me how does the image draw by scroll

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try something like this:
http://jsfiddle.net/Sladkoff/H6vVJ/

Basically you set the svg to `position: fixed;`, and put another div around it that is high enough for the page to scroll.